# Why Eclimd over Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, vim

I was looking for java plugin in Vim. Yesterday I came across Eclimd. After going through the guide to install Eclimd from http://eclim.org/ I am able to run eclimd.

For running eclimd, eclipse is required and has to run as server.
My question is, why to run eclimd over eclipse? What gains do eclimd over eclipse give?

Also, (it's been only few hours that I have used eclimd) it seems Eclipse is more friendly.

Could anyone suggest reasons for the preference of eclimd over eclipse.

Comment: I guess if you are used to VIM but want to use Eclipse functions, eclim is a good way. If you only want to have VIM like editing I suggest something like vrapper, which offers most of the keyboard shortcuts directly in Eclipse: http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/

Comment: romainl's answer is a good summary of the two things. personally, I use vim very heavily, for almost everything, except writing java. I tried eclim, but I cannot get used to it. I have worked with viPlugin with eclipse for many years, for editing part, better than nothing, but cannot compare to vim at all. After used Eclipse 10+ years, recently I changed to IDEA, the ideavim plugin does better than eclipse's vi-plugin. but still cannot reach (even close) real vim's level. I just live with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vim is much better at text editing than Eclipse, even with a Vi-emulation plugin.

Eclipse is much better at understanding your code and interacting with the Java toolchain than Vim, even with all the Java plugins you can find on vim.org.

Eclim is a way to combine the distinctive powers of Vim and Eclipse. If you don't care, by all means don't use it and keep doing what you did before.

Answer (score 0):

Vi doesn't have features for auto complition or code validation afaik for any programming language. It does provide syntax highlighting capabilities , but that's all.
Eclipse provides these features to Eclimd. 
Eclimd is a client to Eclipse, that's why you can't run  it without eclipse.
I hope that clarified it.
BTW: Eclipse does its syntax checking by running the javac (when used for Java programming),
while vi(m) usually doesn't support direct calls to other tools in its extensions.
But if you are focused on Java Development, you should, imho, use an ide. Eclipse is a good one, there are others such as JDeveloper oder Netbeans.
That's not only because the clear structure of projects, the integration into the build process but also because due to the different stages a Java - Project usually has.
It often starts with a desigining period, where you model your application in UML.
While developing, automated functional test will usually be developed, too, they should be designed also. After that there come the integration tests. Most ides suit much better for this when a vi - plugin could.

Comment: Thanks @Ingo Karkat for the suggested syntax edits.